# Custom context menu always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm implementing a custom menu that appears when the user clicks the left mouse button and I'm having trouble trying to set the position (X, Y) of the menu so that the entire menu will be visible no matter which part of the page it opens.

The image below represents the problem:

[image: a busy cat]

The width of the menu increases depending on the text it has, so adjusting its position and height is also a challenge.

```js
var elements = $('#content').find('h1, p, span');

var setMenuPosition = function(x, y) {
  $("#menu").css('top', y);
  $("#menu").css('left', x);
};

var setSelectedText = function() {
  $('#menu').data('text', $(this).text());
};

var openMenu = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  elements.css('border', '1px solid transparent');
  $(this).css('border', '1px dashed #333');
  $('#menu').addClass('active');
  $('#selected-text').text($('#menu').data('text'));
  setMenuPosition(e.pageX, e.pageY);
};

var closeMenu = function() {
  elements.css('border', '1px solid transparent');
  $('#menu').removeClass('active');
};

$('#content').find('h1, p, span').on('mouseenter', setSelectedText);
$('#content').find('h1, p, span').on("click", openMenu);
$('#menu').on('mouseleave', closeMenu);
```

```css
h1,
p,
span {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#content {
  background-color: #e9e9ea;
  padding: 25px;
}

#menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  background-color: #84ce6a;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#my-span {
  background-color: rgb(255, 79, 79);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
  <p>My text</p>
  <p>My another text</p>
  <p>My text <span id="my-span">My span</span>, other part of the same text</p>
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <h4>Selected text is: <span id="selected-text"></span></h4>
  <button>
    Ok
    </button>
</div>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robsonnogueira/295d78ak/

Comment: Did not understand the question

Comment: If you remove `mouseleave` event, the menu will not close. It's not a problem, is a code you've write.

Comment: I think I was not very clear, the menu is working correctly. The problem is that it is appearing in the wrong position. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the Menu **go outside the viewport** you need this logic:

```
// 1. Set menu content
$menuContent.text(ev.currentTarget.textContent);

// 2. Get X, Y click coordinates
let X = ev.clientX;
let Y = ev.clientY;

// 3. Fix X, Y
X = Math.max(0, Math.min(X, $win.width() - $menu.outerWidth(true)) );
Y = Math.max(0, Math.min(Y, $win.height() - $menu.outerHeight(true)) );

// 4. Show menu
$menu.css({left:X, top:Y}).addClass('is-visible');
```

which takes in consideration the window (*viewport*) size and the Menu size (after its content is inserted) - and fixes, modifies the X, Y coordinates accordingly by using a combination of `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`

**Here's an example:**

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $win = $(window);
  const $menu = $('#menu');
  const $menuContent = $('#menu-content');
  
  const menuOpen = (ev) => {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    
    // 1. Set menu content
    $menuContent.text(ev.currentTarget.textContent);
  
    // 2. Get X, Y click coordinates
    let X = ev.clientX;
    let Y = ev.clientY;
        
    // 3. Fix X, Y
    X = Math.max(0, Math.min(X, $win.width() - $menu.outerWidth(true)) );
    Y = Math.max(0, Math.min(Y, $win.height() - $menu.outerHeight(true)) );
    
    // 4. Show menu
    $menu.css({left:X, top:Y}).addClass('is-visible');
  }
  
  const menuClose = () => {
    $menu.removeClass('is-visible');
  }

  // Events
  $(".menu-open").on('click', menuOpen);
  $(".menu-close").on('click', menuClose);
  $(document).on('click', menuClose);
  $menu.on('click', ev => ev.stopPropagation());

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #84ce6a;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.24s, opacity 0.24s;
}

#menu.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

/*Demo only*/
.menu-open{
  position: absolute;
}
.menu-open:nth-child(1) {top: 0; left: 0;}
.menu-open:nth-child(2) {top: 0; right: 0;}
.menu-open:nth-child(3) {bottom: 0; left: 0;}
.menu-open:nth-child(4) {bottom: 0; right: 0;}
```

```html
<span class="menu-open">Click to open menu</span>
<span class="menu-open">Click me</span>
<span class="menu-open">Click here to open menu</span>
<span class="menu-open">Click to open menu</span>

<div id="menu">
  <h3>This is my menu</h3>
  <div id="menu-content"></div>
  <button class="menu-close">CLOSE MENU</button>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

The above can be additionally improved by:

- Make the menu perform on the *"right side"* similarily as on the left side - by first calculating if a point-flip is achievable (anchor the element on the opposite right-top, right-bottom or left-bottom corners), or otherwise-stick to far edge as it does now.
- Fixing the Menu width / height if does not fit in viewport (Some additional CSS for menu content/body scrollbars might be necessary)

Comment: This effect is exactly what I need. I will try to implement and if it works I will mark it as the best answer. Thank you for your help.