# How to keep div always in viewport (without overflowing outside) in javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i make javasript keep a div in the viewport without overflowing?

ex:
User resizes the screen (lets say go to landscape mode without refresh) and now the div is getting cut off due to the viewport getting bigger.

The div is like a tooltip. basically popper without the extra features.

I have tried setting a timeout every 500 ms, to attach the div to the side of the page (which doesnt work at its like a dropdown, needs to be under the button)

ive been using this function to get the out of viewport

```
var isOutOfViewport = function (elem) {

    // Get element's bounding
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Check if it's out of the viewport on each side
    var out = {};
    out.top = bounding.top < 0;
    out.left = bounding.left < 0;
    out.bottom = bounding.bottom > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    out.right = bounding.right > (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    out.any = out.top || out.left || out.bottom || out.right;

    return out;

};var logViewport = function () {
    var isOut = isOutOfViewport(document.querySelector('#in-viewport'));
    if (isOut.any) {
        console.log('Not in the viewport! =(');
    } else {
        console.log('In the viewport! =)');
    }
};
window.addEventListener('scroll', logViewport, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', logViewport, false);
```

My end goal:

Make the div always on screen, without overflowing (like popper js)

Comment: Why don't you set the style attribute or even from CSS? Does this have such HTML?

Comment: Why not used "position: fixed" from css instead? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987519/always-visible-div-while-scrolling)

Comment: the reason for no css, because when the user resizes the screen, the div overflows. what im kinda thinking is, move the div <some> px to make it so it will fit

Comment: i had poorly explained what i needed to do, i found the result i wanted here. (just not a content menu) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655646/custom-context-menu-always-visible)